# Use different parameter data types in same function? (C++)

Tags: c++

So say I had:

```
public: static void print(string message) { }
```

Is there a way I could make it accept other data types **(eg. int, double etc)** in the same function?
So I could call it like `print(7)` and it would work?

Thanks everyone for the answers; in the title I wanted it as the same function because I didn't realise functions could have the same names as each other (like variables). Hence, I thought the only way you could do it was through the same function. As I am quite new to C++, I preferred the method of just using the same function name and doing it with different parameters (the overloading method).

Comment: It is called overloading.

Comment: Just use overloaded methods as it ensures type safety etc

Comment: @user2672165 Overloading is for reusing the name, not the "same function". I presume OP meant the same code, to avoid copying statements, that would make sense. Though, on the second thought I might be wrong.

Comment: @luk32 Overloading seems fine to me. I didn't think that you could have functions with the same name (like variables) so I thought the only option would be to have it in the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create functions with the same name but with different parameters, this is called function overload, for example:

```
void print(char *message) { printf("%s", message); }
void print(int val) { printf("%d", val); }
void print(char ch) { printf("%c", ch); }
```

All above functions are overloaded, see examples of calling:

```
print("Hello World!");
print(10);
print('P');
```

this is only available in C++ (not in C)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise functions could have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the templates are for e.g:

```
template<typename Type>
void print_something(Type something) {
  std::cout << something << '\n';
}
```

The compiler is smart enough to deduce type from parameter. So you can call it like this:

```
print_something("test");
print_something(42);
```

It also works for member functions. What compiler does is it substitutes the `Type` with a concrete type (like `int`, or `char*`, or `std::string`) and produces an overload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++ templates, Template provide generic data types in c++.
see this for more details.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by using templates.
like this:

```
template <class T>
class CTest{
    .
    .
    .
}
template <class T>
static void print::CTest<T>(T message){...}
```

and then specify your variable type while using in your main function.